# Python Tkinter Tk() object snaps to top left corner when maximized

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("350x350")
root.minsize(250, 250)
root.maxsize(500, 500)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this and click the Maximize button (the three buttons on the top right of any program, _◻✖) The window automatically snaps to the top left corner. Is there any way to manipulate this behavior and make it, for instance snap to the center of the screen, or the top right, or the top center?

Comment: ***click the Maximize ... make it, ... center of the screen***: Maximize and Center are contradict, rephrase you question?

Comment: No,System will draw the window from left top corner to the right bottom corner automatically when you press the maximized button.But maybe you could rewrite the button(Use `overrideredirect()` and create button by manually to change the position and size of the window).

Comment: If you maximize it but move the top-left corner to the top-right of the screen, none of the window will be visible. Why would you want that?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to manipulate this behavior and make it, for instance snap to the center of the screen, or the top right, or the top center?

No, there is not. That button is not controlled by tkinter. That button requests that the window manager set the window to a mazimized state. AFAIK, all window managers define that as the window filling the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `<Configure>` event and check the `wm_state()` property. If this method returns 'zoomed' then the window is maximized and you could unmaximise it (`wm_state('normal')`) and reset its position to the screen center using the geometry method.

If you are doing this for a splash-screen or something then this is probably not the right way to go and you should look up wm_overrideredirect or consider making this a toolwindow which does not show a maximize button (`root.wm_attributes('-toolwindow', 1)`).